# face rigging with head movement/rotation too

Tags: rigging

I've just rigged a purchased HD head mesh from 3dscanstore.

I've rigged this with Metarig (removing all boned from spine004 down). Having generated and parented the rig to mesh successfully (with eyes and teeth etc included), the rig works.

However there is no head rotation in the rig. You'll see in the screen-grab that Spine006 is still there but hasn't been generated?

Can I add this to the rig or do I need to start again?

(This is not the updated metarig face)

Blender 3.3.1[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and this is solved by selecting the lower spine bone (Spine bone 004) and unchecking **connect chain** in the **object data properties** before generating the rig.

Once generated, all motion of the head is there

[image]